# Avoid to add components manually

Tags: installation, wix, components

I have a folder with around 50 dlls. Is there any way to add those as each component in the wix code. rather than write those 50 manually???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link works well for me and it is easy than the command prompt.
All the things can be handled in the setup project.
http://blog.martindoms.com/2012/02/27/how-to-include-a-large-directory-tree-in-a-wix-installer-using-a-visual-studio-wix-project/

Answer (score 5):

The `heat.exe` tool provided in the WiX toolset can generate a .wxs file by scanning files in a directory. That's the easiest way to get started quickly. Something like:

```
heat dir path\to\directory\with\files -cg YourComponentGroup -ag -o generated.wxs
```

There are a bunch of other options available as well, that `heat.exe -?` will show you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I couldn't get you clearly. How to use that heat.exe?

Comment: ya i tried in cmd prompt but it says...heat is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: by adding the HeatDirectory tag also...we can generate wxs file inside the setup project...Can anyone give that code.

Comment: @Kowsika Try `"%wix%\bin\heat" -?`. Don't forget the quotes.